# Should a function containing loop be async in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to NodeJS and I am not really sure how should the following function be declared. The function contains only a for loop which generates a string. There are no "heavy-weight" calculations done.

**Variant 1:**

```
function getRandomString(arg) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // ...
    }

    return string;
}

var randomString = getRandomString(arg);
// ... an async code which will use the string
```

**Variant 2:** Or should I make it async (async-style)? It would look something like this:

```
function getRandomString(arg, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // ...
    }

    callback(string);
}

getRandomString(arg, function(randomString) {
    // Async code...
});
```

Comment: Rule of thumb for node "all code runs at the same time, except yours". If you are running a for loop on the node runtime, that for loop is hogging node no matter how you return the result.

Comment: If it is a fast function, I would tend to go with the first form just because of its simplicity and I think writing too many callbacks gets messy. But then again, I'm not very familiar with performance on node, so I'm not sure which would perform better.

Comment: it makes no difference to have a callback, the heavy bit is a `for` loop and that's always synchronous

Comment: I thought that... So basically if I've got some loop (Few iteration - very fast) it absolutely doesn't matter how I am gonna use it (Sync/Async because it is same) ,but when I am using some loop for more complex calculations (For example it will take 5 seconds and it is often used) it is better to fork new process for that, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or should I make it async? So something like this:
>
> ```
> function getString(arg, callback) {
>     for(var i = 0;i<100;i++) {
>         // ...
>     }
>     callback(string);
> }
> ```

No. That code does still run synchronousls, only with an odd callback style for returning the result. Since JS does no tail call optimisation or has continuation support, it just introduces the pyramid of doom without any benefit.

Do not use this unless you really make it asynchronous (`setTimeout`, `nextTick` etc), for example to defer the single loop iterations.

Comment: So for async function I should put content of a loop "within" nextTick? As I said above loop is fast (Approx. 0.5ms) so it doesn't matter or does it?

Comment: For fast loops like yours, the overhead of making it asynchronous is too big. Do not try it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit from making it "asynchronous". In fact, the code will run synchronously, with the getString method only exiting after the callback is complete.

The only decision you really have to make is one of coding style (Do you want it to *seem* asynchronous or not.)

```
function getString(arg, callback)
{
    for(var i = 0;i<100;i++)
    {
        // ...
    }
    //Callback will execute synchronously, and you will wait here until it is complete
    callback(string);
}
```